# USB hard drive works when it is FAT32/HFS/NTFS but doesn't work when I write a Linux image to it

Tags: linux, external-hard-drive

I have a SeaGate Expansion Desktop Drive (3TB) and I am encountering some weird behavior.

When I write a Linux image to it (using Etcher), I can't boot from the SeaGate Expansion hard drive and it isn't mountable in any OS on any computer (not even Linux). I tried Raspbian, Ubuntu, and some other Linux images. When I write the same Linux image to any other USB hard drive it works totally fine, I can boot from it and mount it, so I guess that means it's not the images I'm trying to write.

When I format it to HFS(+) (with a Mac) / NTFS (with a Windows) / FAT32 (with either) it works perfectly. I can mount it, read from it, write to it in any OS (except for NTFS being read-only in MacOS and HFS+ not recognized in Windows of course, but that's expected behavior).

```
Error mounting /dev/sdb1 at /media/(***)/Ubuntu 17.10 amd64: Command-line 'mount-t "iso9660" -o
"uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,mode=0400,dmode=0500"

"dev/sdb1" "/media/(***)/Ubuntu 17.10 amd64" exited with non-zero exit status 32:
mount:/media/(***)/Ubuntu 17.10 amd64: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on 
/dev/sdb1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

(I replaced my username obviously)

Comment: 3TB drives require GPT. Maybe that's the reason?

Comment: Any suggestions on how to write a Linux image to a >3TB drive with GPT? Or should I just use smaller drives?

Comment: What exactly are you talking about? What do you mean by "Linux image"?

Comment: The bootable Linux images/installers that I download from the distro their website to install Linux on my computers.

Comment: Those are supposed to be written ("burned") into USB sticks, not massive external HDDs. It may work on those with MBR ("msdos") partitioning but larger drives require GPT.